# Training step not executing in pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am working to finetune a t5 model to summarize Amazon reviews. I am following this tutorial here: https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-a-t5-transformer-for-any-summarization-task-82334c64c81

I noticed that the training_step in my code is never being executed as the training loss remains "NaN" throughout the epoch. However, the validation_step is computed fine.

I already confirmed that there are no empty strings in the data and have tried multiple batch sizes.

This is the error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-45d4afebefac> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.fit(model)

8 frames
<ipython-input-46-00fddffa2209> in training_epoch_end(self, outputs)
    134         print("OUTPUTS")
    135         print(outputs)
--> 136         avg_train_loss = torch.stack([x["loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
    137         tensorboard_logs = {"avg_train_loss": avg_train_loss}
    138         return {"avg_train_loss": avg_train_loss, "log": tensorboard_logs, 'progress_bar': tensorboard_logs}

RuntimeError: stack expects a non-empty TensorList
```

I found that the training_step function is never being executed by adding print statements inside the training_step function.

Below is my code for the T5FineTuner class (sorry I can't be any more concise):

```
class T5FineTuner(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hparams):
        super(T5FineTuner, self).__init__()
        self.hparams = hparams        
        self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(hparams.model_name_or_path)
        self.tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(hparams.tokenizer_name_or_path)
        self.rouge_metric = load_metric('rouge') 
        
        if self.hparams.freeze_embeds:
            self.freeze_embeds()
        if self.hparams.freeze_encoder:
            self.freeze_params(self.model.get_encoder())
            assert_all_frozen(self.model.get_encoder())
            
            
        n_observations_per_split = {
            "train": self.hparams.n_train,
            "validation": self.hparams.n_val,
            "test": self.hparams.n_test,
        }
        self.n_obs = {k: v if v >= 0 else None for k, v in n_observations_per_split.items()}
        
    
    def freeze_params(self, model):
        for par in model.parameters():
            par.requires_grad = False
            
            
    def freeze_embeds(self):
        """Freeze token embeddings and positional embeddings for bart, just token embeddings for t5."""
        try:
            self.freeze_params(self.model.model.shared)
            for d in [self.model.model.encoder, self.model.model.decoder]:
                freeze_params(d.embed_positions)
                freeze_params(d.embed_tokens)
        except AttributeError:
            self.freeze_params(self.model.shared)
            for d in [self.model.encoder, self.model.decoder]:
                self.freeze_params(d.embed_tokens)
    
    def lmap(self, f, x):
        """list(map(f, x))"""
        return list(map(f, x))
    

    def is_logger(self):
        return True
    
    
    def parse_score(self, result):
        return {k: round(v.mid.fmeasure * 100, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
        
    def forward(
      self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, decoder_input_ids=None, decoder_attention_mask=None, labels=None
  ):
        return self.model(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
            decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
            labels=labels,
    )

    def _step(self, batch):
        labels = batch["target_ids"]
        labels[labels[:, :] == self.tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100
        # print(labels)
        outputs = self(
            input_ids=batch["source_ids"],
            attention_mask=batch["source_mask"],
            labels=labels,
            decoder_attention_mask=batch['target_mask']
        )
        # print(outputs)

        loss = outputs[0]
        return loss
    
    
    def ids_to_clean_text(self, generated_ids):
        gen_text = self.tokenizer.batch_decode(
            generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True
        )
        return self.lmap(str.strip, gen_text)
    
    
    def _generative_step(self, batch) :
        
        t0 = time.time()
        
        generated_ids = self.model.generate(
            batch["source_ids"],
            attention_mask=batch["source_mask"],
            use_cache=True,
            decoder_attention_mask=batch['target_mask'],
            max_length=150, 
            num_beams=2,
            repetition_penalty=2.5, 
            length_penalty=1.0, 
            early_stopping=False,
        )
        preds = self.ids_to_clean_text(generated_ids)
        target = self.ids_to_clean_text(batch["target_ids"])
            
        gen_time = (time.time() - t0) / batch["source_ids"].shape[0]  
    
        loss = self._step(batch)
        # print("LOSS _generative_step")
        # print(loss)
        base_metrics = {'val_loss': loss}
#         rouge: Dict = self.calc_generative_metrics(preds, target)
        summ_len = np.mean(self.lmap(len, generated_ids))
        base_metrics.update(gen_time=gen_time, gen_len=summ_len, preds=preds, target=target)
        self.rouge_metric.add_batch(preds, target)
        
        # rouge_results = self.rouge_metric.compute() 
        # rouge_dict = self.parse_score(rouge_results)
        # base_metrics.update(rouge1=rouge_dict['rouge1'], rougeL=rouge_dict['rougeL'])
        
        return base_metrics
    

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        print("training_step")
        print(batch)
        loss = self._step(batch)

        tensorboard_logs = {"train_loss": loss}
        print("LOSS")
        print(loss)
        return {"loss": loss, "log": tensorboard_logs}
  
    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        print("OUTPUTS")
        print(outputs)
        avg_train_loss = torch.stack([x["loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        tensorboard_logs = {"avg_train_loss": avg_train_loss}
        return {"avg_train_loss": avg_train_loss, "log": tensorboard_logs, 'progress_bar': tensorboard_logs}

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        print("validation_step")
        return self._generative_step(batch)
    
  
    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        
        avg_loss = torch.stack([x["val_loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        tensorboard_logs = {"val_loss": avg_loss}
        
        rouge_results = self.rouge_metric.compute() 
        rouge_dict = self.parse_score(rouge_results)
    
        tensorboard_logs.update(rouge1=rouge_dict['rouge1'], rougeL=rouge_dict['rougeL'])
        
        ## Clear out the lists for next epoch
        self.target_gen= []
        self.prediction_gen=[]
        return {"avg_val_loss": avg_loss, 
                "rouge1" : rouge_results['rouge1'],
                "rougeL" : rouge_results['rougeL'],
                "log": tensorboard_logs, 'progress_bar': tensorboard_logs}

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        "Prepare optimizer and schedule (linear warmup and decay)"

        model = self.model
        no_decay = ["bias", "LayerNorm.weight"]
        optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters() if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": self.hparams.weight_decay,
            },
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters() if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": 0.0,
            },
        ]
        optimizer = AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr=self.hparams.learning_rate, eps=self.hparams.adam_epsilon)
        self.opt = optimizer
        return [optimizer]
  
    def optimizer_step(self, epoch, batch_idx, optimizer, optimizer_idx, second_order_closure=None, using_native_amp=False, optimizer_closure=None, on_tpu=None, using_lbfgs=None):
        # if self.trainer.use_tpu:
        #     xm.optimizer_step(optimizer)
        # else:
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        self.lr_scheduler.step()
  
    def get_tqdm_dict(self):
        tqdm_dict = {"loss": "{:.3f}".format(self.trainer.avg_loss), "lr": self.lr_scheduler.get_last_lr()[-1]}

        return tqdm_dict
    

    def train_dataloader(self):
        print("train_dataloader")   
        n_samples = self.n_obs['train']
        print(n_samples)
        dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.hparams.train_batch_size, num_workers=4)
        print(len(dataloader.dataset))
        print(self.hparams.train_batch_size * max(1, self.hparams.n_gpu))
        print(self.hparams.gradient_accumulation_steps)
        print(float(self.hparams.num_train_epochs))
        t_total = (
            (len(dataloader.dataset) // (self.hparams.train_batch_size * max(1, self.hparams.n_gpu)))
            # // self.hparams.gradient_accumulation_steps
            * float(self.hparams.num_train_epochs)
        )
        print(t_total)
        scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
            self.opt, num_warmup_steps=self.hparams.warmup_steps, num_training_steps=t_total
        )
        self.lr_scheduler = scheduler
        return dataloader

    def val_dataloader(self):
        n_samples = self.n_obs['validation']
        # validation_dataset = get_dataset(tokenizer=self.tokenizer, type_path="validation", num_samples=n_samples, args=self.hparams)
        
        return DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size=self.hparams.eval_batch_size, num_workers=4)
    
    
    def test_dataloader(self):
        n_samples = self.n_obs['test']
        # test_dataset = get_dataset(tokenizer=self.tokenizer, type_path="test", num_samples=n_samples, args=self.hparams)
        
        return DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=self.hparams.test_batch_size, num_workers=4)
```

Below are my parameters:

```
args_dict = dict(
    output_dir="", # path to save the checkpoints
    model_name_or_path='t5-small',
    tokenizer_name_or_path='t5-small',
    max_input_length=512,
    max_output_length=150,
    freeze_encoder=False,
    freeze_embeds=False,
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    weight_decay=0.0,
    adam_epsilon=1e-8,
    warmup_steps=0,
    train_batch_size=20,
    eval_batch_size=20,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=8,
    n_gpu=1,
    resume_from_checkpoint=None, 
    val_check_interval = 0.05, 
    n_val=1000,
    n_train=-1,
    n_test=-1,
    early_stop_callback=False,
    fp_16=False, # if you want to enable 16-bit training then install apex and set this to true
    opt_level='O1', # you can find out more on optimisation levels here https://nvidia.github.io/apex/amp.html#opt-levels-and-properties
    max_grad_norm=1.0, # if you enable 16-bit training then set this to a sensible value, 0.5 is a good default
    seed=42,
)
```

Comment: hey, any updates on that please? I am running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this code is quite outdated. What makes this conflict is the `optimizer_step()` method. I just commented out this whole segment below and it worked for me. If you want to do any custom logic in this function, better to consult the latest code on [GitHub](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/blob/f29ecbfd909ff431ef837fcc8ebff451e897cb0b/tests/trainer/test_training_loop.py#L61).

```
def optimizer_step(self, epoch, batch_idx, optimizer, optimizer_idx, second_order_closure=None, using_native_amp=False,on_tpu=None,using_lbfgs=None, optimizer_closure=None):
        if self.trainer.use_tpu:
            xm.optimizer_step(optimizer)
        else:
            optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        self.lr_scheduler.step()
```